# Android: Using BLE without a bespoke GATT Server

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to use the BLE Current Time Service (0x1805) in conjunction with a BLE enabled device. My question is: Do I "need" to create an App to manage BLE connectivity and return results for the Current Time Service to my device, or does Android somehow implement a generic GATT server?

If so, how do I enable that?

So far, my BLE pairing attempts have simply errored out on the device side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a generic GATT Server on Android, but there are apps that can do the job for you. I would suggest starting with the [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile) app which is able to start a GATT server with a pre defined current time service.